# Pattern match using smart constructor

Tags: haskell

Is there a way to pattern match smart constructors, outside of its module?

Something like this:

```
import MyModule (thing)

fn (thing 3) = True
```

without being able to write this:

```
fn (Thing 3) = True
```

where `thing` is a smart constructor for `Thing`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pattern matching on a private data constructor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33722381/pattern-matching-on-a-private-data-constructor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define this in `MyModule` and export it:

```
extract :: Thing -> Int
extract (Thing x) = x
```

Use the [view patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

fn :: Thing -> Bool
fn (extract -> 3) = True
```